# Обработчик двойного клика строки в таблице.JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Как реализовать обработчик двойного клика в таблице. При одиночном нажатии нашел решение

```
table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showPersonDetails(newValue));
```

Но требуется чтобы при двойном нажатии создавался новый фрейм в зависимости от выбранной строчки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TableView<MyType> table = new TableView<>();

//...

table.setRowFactory( tv -> {
    TableRow<MyType> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (! row.isEmpty()) ) {
            MyType rowData = row.getItem();
            //Делайте, что требуется с элементом.
        }
    });
    return row ;
});
```

Comment: двойное нажатие срабатывает отлично, только вот почему то 
 rowData после определения остается пустым.

Comment: Ваш код не вижу, но могу догадываться, что ваша rowData замещается новой.

Comment: благодарю.буду разбираться!)

Comment: Зачем же постить неработающий код. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513906/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-tablerow-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC-javafx

Comment: Код рабочий. Был вопрос как обработать двойной клик - было показано, как это сделать на простом примере (поскольку как человек подгружает данные, код представлен не был, то просто создавалась новая строка). В дальнейшем этот пример адаптируется парочкой изменений, но это уже другая задача, которая была решена в другом вопросе. (Причину, почему "не работало" у человека, была указана уже в этой теме)