# Выбранный TableRow оказывается пустым

Tags: java, javafx

Есть таблица,при выборе строчки которой,должны производиться манипуляции.
строчка выбирается но данные этой строки остаются пустыми, то есть tablerow не содержит никакой информации.

```
    @FXML
    private volatile TableView<User> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User,String> spisok;
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        spisok.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());

        table.setRowFactory (tv-> {
            TableRow<User> row=new TableRow<> ();
            row.setOnMouseClicked (event->{
            if(event.getClickCount ()==2&&(!row.isEmpty ())){
            User rowData=row.getItem ();//почему то rowData пустой экземпляр класса User
                System.out.print (rowData+rowData.getLogin ()+rowData.getIP ());
                new Priem ().Priem (rowData.getLogin ());
            }
        });
        return row; });     
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в этом месте:

```
TableRow<User> row = new TableRow<>();
```

Вы создаете новый экземпляр TableRow, который содержит новые значения, в данном случае - пустые, по-этому вы ничего не можете с него получить. Вам нужно вытащить TableRow из вашей таблицы, а не создавать новый. [Инструкция](http://java-buddy.blogspot.in/2013/03/javafx-get-row-data-from-tableview.html).